# Replace the null value with a value in the column

Tags: sql, sql-server

If there is both `null` and numeric value in the offset and duration columns, I want to replace that `null` value with that numeric value for that particular set Monday to Sunday.

```
laboraccountid | weekday   | offset | duration
---------------+-----------+--------+---------
190685         | Monday    | 200    | 500
190685         | Tuesday   | 200    | 500
190685         | Wednesday | null   | null
190685         | Thursday  | null   | null
190685         | Friday    | 200    | 500
190685         | Sunday    | 200    | 500
125686         | Monday    | 1435   | 5687
125686         | Tuesday   | 1435   | 5687
125686         | Wednesday | 1435   | 5687
125686         | Thursday  | 1435   | 5687
125686         | Friday    | 1435   | 5687
125686         | Saturday  | 1435   | 5687
125686         | Sunday    | 1435   | 5687
```

I tried using the `case` statement but I am unable to do it.

Comment: SO is about helping you, not doing it for you, so have a go and see how far you can get.

Comment: Look into `coalesce` function.

Comment: Adding your desired result set will help to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like, adding a CTE to get the replacement `NULL` values grouped by the account id.:

```
WITH BestValue
AS
(
SELECT
    laboraccountid,
    MAX(offset) AS offset,
    MAX(duration) AS duration
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE
    offset IS NOT NULL AND duration IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    laboraccountid
)
SELECT
    MT.laboraccountid,
    MT.weekday,
    ISNULL(MT.offset,BV.offset) as offset,
    ISNULL(MT.duration, BV.duration) as duration
FROM
    MyTable AS MT
    JOIN
    BestValue AS BV
    ON MT.laboraccountid = BV.laboraccountid
```

This will give you the maximum value for that week as the `NULL` replacement.

This assumes that there is at least one non-null value for each week.

The `case` equivalent is

```
    CASE
        WHEN offset IS NULL THEN BV.offset
        ELSE offset
    END AS MT.offset,
    ....
```

Comment: I think isnull function will not work  because I am trying to replace the null with the values in the set from Monday to Sunday  in that set it is 200 and 500 what if the other set have different values

Comment: I am sure that it will. Why do you think it won't? Try it.

Comment: i tried the case statement it is replacing every null in the column to 200 but i want to replace depends on the laboraccountid

Comment: Please give your required results. Do you mean that you want to use the values for that week. Please clarify what it is that you want.

Comment: i want to replace the null values with the values for that  particular week associated with the labor account

Comment: I have updated my answer to give week specific replacement values.

Comment: Tested on my end, based on given table values. I had to add appropriate aliases due to ambiguity, but it worked.  I can add sqlfiddle if necessary.